# c++ Copy constructors and destructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, custom-data-type

I am learning constructors and Destructors in c++; Help me grasp my mistakes even if they are silly...

HERE is a code I have written to perform addition using classes in c++; This creates two summands of *datatype* num and employs the constructor *sum()* to perform sum of the two numbers; However when everything was goin' alright, I stumbled upon creating a copy constructor for num , (Although not necessary but still for practice)... without the dynamic object of the class *sum* it is not possible to run the code anyway(without removing the copy constructor)... Help me improve my code and my mistakes in the code below; *Also I wanna know how to make use of the copy constructor in this program; the problem being that in the destructor the delete operation is being performed multiple times on the same piece of memory (I suppose)*

Here's my Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<new>
using namespace std;
class num
{
public:
    int *a;
    num(int x)
    {
        try
        {
            a=new int;
        }
        catch(bad_alloc xa)
        {
            cout<<"1";
            exit(1);
        }
        *a=x;
    }
    num(){  }
    num(const num &ob)
    {
        try
        {
            a=new int;
        }
        catch(bad_alloc xa)
        {
            cout<<"1''";
            exit(2);
        }
        *a=*(ob.a);
    }
    ~num()
    { 
        cout<<"Destruct!!!";
        delete a;
    }
};


class sum:public num
{
 public:
     int add;
     sum(num n1,num n2)
     {
         add=*(n1.a)+*(n2.a);
     }
     int getsum()
     {
         return add;
     }
};

int main()
{
    num x=58;
    num y=82;
    sum *s=new sum(x,y);
    cout<<s->getsum();
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For code reviews you might consider going to [CodeReview Stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `num(){  }` this is **extremely** wrong. You cannot leave your pointer data member uninitialised.

Comment: Why does `sum` need to inherit from `num`? `sum(num n1,num n2)` prefer taking by `const num&` instead. `sum(const num& n1, const num& n2)`

Comment: I don't see the need for `num` to hold a `int *`, rather than just an `int`. Or for it to exist *at all*. Just operate on `int`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may miss something - didn't use new/delete for too long, but tried to correct all what I noticed.

P.S. always use smart pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

int* allocate(const char* err_msg, int exit_code)
{
    int* a = nullptr;
    try
    {
        a = new int;
    }
    catch (bad_alloc&)
    {
        cout << err_msg << endl;
        exit(exit_code);
    }
    return a;
}

class num
{
    int* a = nullptr; // always should be initialized here

public:
    num() noexcept : a(nullptr) // or here
    {}

    /*explicit*/ num(int x) : a(allocate("1", 1))
    {
        *a = x;
    }

    num(const num& ob) : a(allocate("1''", 2))
    {
        *a = *(ob.a);
    }

    // rule of zero/three/five
    // default copy assignment will copy pointer and one int will be leaked and one will be deleted twice
    num& operator =(const num& ob)
    {
        if (&ob == this)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        *a = *(ob.a);
        return *this;
    }

    ~num()
    { 
        cout << "Destruct!!!";
        delete a;
        a = nullptr; // usefull for debug
    }

    int value() const
    {
        if (a == nullptr)
        {
            throw runtime_error("a == nullptr");
        }
        return *a;
    }
};

class sum
{
    int add = 0;

public:
    sum(const num& n1, const num& n2)
    {
        add = n1.value() + n2.value();
    }

    int getsum() const
    {
        return add;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const num x = 58;
    const num y = 82;
    const sum* s = new sum(x, y);
    cout << s->getsum() << endl;
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help;

Comment: One more; since I am new to constructors and exceptions so can you please explain the lines _num() noexcept: a(nullptr)_ and the rule of 0 3 and 5?

Comment: There are Dozens of errors cropping out during compilations ; I cannot debug these errors

Comment: @ArijitDey Wich compiler do you use? Here is an explanation of rule of 0/3/5: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: @ArijitDey num() noexcept: a(nullptr) is a default consructor initializing a with 0.